# Google app engine accidentally deleted classes files?

Tags: java, git, google-app-engine, classnotfoundexception

i ran a `git clean -f -d` command because i had some undesired files. this, however, caused me to somehow accidentally delete everything out of `war/WEB-INF/classes/com/`

now my server code doesn't seem to compile anymore. instead it keeps giving me this `ClassNotFoundException` :

```
WARNING: EXCEPTION 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.corp.something.SomeServlet
```

how do i re-generate these files?

and the bigger picture question is -> am i supposed to include things in git that's in `war/WEB-INF/classes/com/` ??

Answer (score 0):

Oh nvm. whew. thank goodness. you just have to use Eclipse -> project clean, and have it rebuild. wow that scared me shitless.